# Google Places API Logs

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-cloud-platform

On Friday, I received an invoice from Google. They ask me to pay 1000€ for services I never used. I assume somebody had access to one of my API key. My first instinct was to delete all the keys to avoid more damage. But now, I may have a clue on who used the key. I wanted to know if it is possible to retrieve a deleted API key? And even if it is not possible, is it possible to check all the requests received by a Google Cloud Project (i.e all the calls from API keys related to my project)?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the use of a third-party service and doesn't involve programming.

Answer (score 2):

You can check usage by API key in your developer console for the last 30 days. Select Places API to check usage graph at

`https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/apis/places-backend.googleapis.com/metrics?authuser=1&project=YOUR_PROJECT_ID&duration=P30D`

You will see a combo box that allows group results by credentials (API keys) as shown in my screenshot

[image]

And below if you click Show more link you will see a table with usage per API key. Something similar to the following screenshot

[image]

I'm not sure if deleted API keys appear in this report, but Google support team can retrieve information about deleted API keys. In this case you should file support case via https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support.

I hope this helps!